# How to search as csv. file in a column that is in "date" format

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm trying to write a code that will search an excel database for a month of birth (format DD/MM/YYYY). I'm not sure how to search the file as it is written in "date" format, whereas all other files are in "general" format. Does anyone know how to do this?

My code:

```
import csv
dob = input('Input dob (DD/MM/YYYY): ')
month = dob.split('/')
with open('AddressBook.csv', newline='') as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile)
    for row in reader:
        if int(month[1]) in row:
            print(row)
        else:
            ()
```

This is the excel address book in question. (There are no real names or contact info)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLcmi.png

Comment: What does not work with your current code?  Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

You should split the date of birth in your data as well. Here's an example:

```
import csv
dob = input('Input dob (DD/MM/YYYY): ')
date, month, year = dob.split("/")

with open('AddressBook.csv', newline='') as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile)
    for row in reader:
        row_date, row_month, row_year = row[6].split("/")
        if row_month == month:
            print(row) # or whatever you want to print..
```

As your date of birth is on the sixth index, you split that. Unpacking the splitted list makes it a little nicer to work with..

You could also use `csv.DictReader` and a list comprehension:

```
_, month, __ = dob.split("/")
with open("AddressBook.csv") as myfile:
    matched = [row for row in csv.DictReader(myfile) if month == row[6].split("/")[1]]
```

Which will result in a list of rows that match the date of birth specified.

Comment: Thankyou so much! You've helped me a great deal, if I coulld vote up your answer... I would! :)

Comment: @user3576688 You can accept the answer [like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers).